# Training tff metrics on federated training data of clients

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm).

Here I perform training on federated train data:

```py
for round in range(15):
    server_state = federated_algorithm.next(server_state, federated_train_data)
```

and then evaluate the testing set.

How can I get the tff training (accuracy/loss) metrics in custom code of federated learning?

Earlier, I was using:

```py
iterative_process = tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(MnistModel, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02))
```

and then I was able to print tff metrics:

```py
print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))
```

But I don't understant how I can show tff metrics in my custom tensorflow federated training process.